# Shiny beginner: selectInput is not working properly in case of sql db load

Tags: sql, r, events, shiny

For my first shiny application, I want to load data from sql and display it in a table. This works fine, when I only use text input in the sidePanel menu. I want to display all available databases in a drop-down at first. Next, I want the all schemas for that db displayed in a second drop-down, once the db is chosen. Finally I want to select tables in a drop-down, displayed according to the utilized schema and db.

However, I already run into an error (Error in : invalid connection option "SQLdb"), when I am trying to just select the db via drop-down.

```
# lib
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

# preload
cc<- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
               dbname = "postgres",
               host = "localhost",
               port = "5432",
               user="postgres",
               password="xxxx") 
db_list <- dbGetQuery(cc, "SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = FALSE")
db_list <- db_list %>% dplyr::filter(!grepl("postgres", datname))


#### UI --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Load Data",
               tabName = "load_data",
               icon = icon("database")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "load_data",
              fluidPage( 
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    #textInput("SQLdb", "Database", value="shiny_data"),
                    selectInput(inputId = "SQLdb",
                                label = "Select Database",
                                choices = db_list,
                                selected = "shiny_data"),
                    textInput("schema", "Schema", value="m4_monthly"),
                    textInput("table", "Table", value="m4_samples"),
                    textInput("host", "Host", value="localhost"),
                    textInput("port", "Port", value="5432"),
                    textInput("user", "User", value = "postgres"),
                    passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                    actionButton("connectDB", "Load DB table"),
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    textOutput("test"),
                    uiOutput("tabnames_ui"),
                    tableOutput("out"),
                    dataTableOutput("table")
                  )))))))


#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#### SERVER

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe ({
  updateSelectInput(session,
                    "SQLdb",
                    choices = db_list,
                    selected = "shiny_data"
                    )
  })
  # database load 
  con=reactiveValues(cc=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$connectDB{

    con$cc<- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                       dbname = input$SQLdb,
                       host = input$host,
                       port = input$port,
                       user=input$user,
                       password=input$passwd) 
    table_id <- DBI::Id(
      schema  = input$schema,
      table   = input$table)
    data <- dbReadTable(con$cc, name = table_id, value = input$table)
    dbDisconnect(con$cc)
    data.frame(data)
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable(data)
    
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Typo? Change `SQLdb = input$SQLdb` to `dbname = input$SQLdb` in your last call to `dbConnect`.

Comment: Corrected the typo, but it did not solve the issue. I am still unable to establish a connection. Seems, that the query only sends schema name and table name to the DB